# Sendkeys in vbscript is truncating the keys passed in putty terminal

Tags: linux, vbscript, putty, plink

I 've written a vbscript to automate putty commands using plink.

On sending the linux commands,via vbscript's sendkeys method ,it randomly truncates characters on being passed to the putty terminal.

```
   Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   WshShell.Run "plink username@hostname -pw password* "

   WScript.Sleep 100

   WshShell.SendKeys "cd abcd",True 'In Putty only cd ab is displayed

   WScript.Sleep 100

   WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}",True
```

What could be the possible alternative to this?[In Putty terminal sendkeys displays only cd ab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZPQl.png)

Answer (score 1):

[SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29) is a last-ditch effort to try to automate "applications that have no automation interface." It simulates hitting keys on the keyboard, and is easily unreliable if an application isn't expecting keys hit that quickly, if the focus changes from where you were expecting, or really if anything odd happens at all.

Seeing as the [purpose of plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) is to be used in an automated way by scripts, it feels like for whatever you're actually trying to do, you must be trying to do it the hard way. Just use plink to [run the command you want](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-batch) to run directly, and don't try to use SendKeys to automate it.